# MS SQL Index for Search Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have an AJAX quick search function where users search for names in a directory. The query looks like this where name is the parameter:

```
SELECT TOP 30 * 
FROM   CONTACT c 
WHERE  ( c.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' 
          OR c.LAST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' ) 
        OR ( c.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + c.LAST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' ) 
        OR ( c.LAST_NAME + ' ' + c.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' ) 
ORDER  BY LAST_NAME, 
          FIRST_NAME
```

What is the best type of index or indexes to have to support this type of query? Or should I construct the query differently to optimize performance? Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your best options are:

1. Look at your query plan to see if there are issues. If it's hard to understand ask questions or look here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1873/how-to-read-sql-server-graphical-query-execution-plans/
2. Look in the database itself in the sys.dm_db_missing_index_details table and see if there are missing indices and evaluate the suggestions as described here: http://www.danielahill.com/Blog/SQL_Server_Find_Add_Missing_Indexes.aspx
3. Look at the performance of the SQL Server machine itself (cpu low, disk activity low)
4. Look at the performance of the application

I think the performance of queries varies a lot based on the data that's in them and how easy it is for the database to cache information and it's hard to give a lot of specific advice.

Comment: Great suggestions. Looking at the execution plan helped a lot and I created a new index that works quite nicely now. I'm not as familiar with the execution plan view as I should be so thanks for reminding me of it. As for performance, the site hasn't launched yet, but I want to optimize this since it runs onkeyup(). The new index already shaved 2 seconds off the execution.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you may try:

```
create index IX_CONTACT_Last_First on CONTACT (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME);
```

Though, probably, there will be no much benefit from it with using `like` (in comparison to exact match condition), but if there are quite a number of other columns in the table, at least it may help doing scan over less pages of data.

You shouldn't use `*`, if only a part of columns are needed among those `*` actually, and should specify necessary columns directly (e.g. `select top (30) ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PHONE, EMAIL from ...`), and you may try include them into index:

```
create index IX_CONTACT_Last_First on CONTACT (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
    include (PHONE, EMAIL, ID);
```

Also, I'm not sure, but it seems that some conditions in the `where` clause are redundant, and you may try doing less checks:

```
SELECT TOP (30) FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM CONTACT c 
WHERE ( c.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + c.LAST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' ) 
    OR ( c.LAST_NAME + ' ' + c.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%#name#%' ) 
ORDER BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME;
```

Comment: I knew I was going to get called out on the * after I posted it! I'm working to figure out exactly what I need. Part of the issue is that the user can specify which columns they want to see back. Thanks very much for catching the redundancy - you are right! The first part is not needed.